# ¿Cómo puedo guardar datos desde un botón (HTML5) y mostrarlos en una tabla y luego los nodos subirlos a Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, firebase

Necesito ingresar identificación, nombre y usuario en cajas de texto. Luego guardarlas con un botón y presentarlas en un tabla; subir los nodos de estos elementos a Firebase.

Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  document.querySelector('#btnGuardar').addEventListener('click', function(){
        identificacion = document.querySelector('#txtIdentificacion').value;
        nombre = document.querySelector('#txtNombre').value;
        usuario = document.querySelector('#txtUsuario').value;
    }) 
})
```

HTML:

```
<h1 style = "color: rgb(0, 175, 175);">Manta</h1>
<h4 style = "color: rgb(4, 152, 211); font-style: italic;">Take it faster</h4>

<label for="">Identificación: </label>
<input type="text" id="txtIdentificacion"><br>
<label for="">Nombre: </label>
<input type="text" id="txtNombre"><br>
<label for="">Usuario: </label> 
<input type="text" id="txtUsuario"><br>


<button id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te presentaré a continuación 2 soluciones, una simple donde solo guardamos 1 registro a la vez y los datos mostrados en la tabla son traídos desde `firebase` y otra un poco más complicada donde guardamos múltiples registros y los datos en la tabla están almacenados locamente hasta ser mandados a `firebase`.

> Nota: hay tener en cuenta tu configuración de escritura y lectura en firebase para el funcionamiento de este código.

Para la solución simple te dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style = "color: rgb(0, 175, 175);">Manta</h1>
  <h4 style = "color: rgb(4, 152, 211); font-style: italic;">Take it faster</h4>
  <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();return submitHandler()">
    <label for="">Identificación: </label>
    <input required type="text" id="txtIdentificacion"><br>
    <label for="">Nombre: </label>
    <input required type="text" id="txtNombre"><br>
    <label for="">Usuario: </label> 
    <input required type="text" id="txtUsuario"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar">Guardar</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div>
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Identificación</th>
        <th>Nombre</th> 
        <th>Usuario</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- table-rows will be auto inserted here -->
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript (archivo main.js)

```
// contains the data stored in firebase database
let data = [];

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

async function getData() {
  try {
    const response = await firebase.database().ref('usuarios').once('value');
    const obj = response.val();
    for (const key in obj) {
      data.push({
        id: key,
        ...obj[key],
      });
    }
    createTable();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('getData error', error);
  }
}

function createTable() {
  const container = document.getElementById('table');
  if (container) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const element = data[i];
      // create a tr
      const tr = document.createElement('tr');
      for (const key in element) {
        if (element.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== 'id') {
          const dataField = element[key];
          // create a td
          const td = document.createElement('td');
          td.innerText = dataField;
          tr.appendChild(td);
        }
      }
      container.appendChild(tr);
    }
  }
}

async function submitHandler() {
  try {
    // inputs
    const identificacionEl = document.getElementById('txtIdentificacion');
    const nombreEl = document.getElementById('txtNombre');
    const usuarioEl = document.getElementById('txtUsuario');
    // input values
    const identificacion = identificacionEl.value;
    const nombre = nombreEl.value;
    const usuario = usuarioEl.value;

    if (identificacion && nombre && usuario) {
      const payload = {
        identificacion,
        nombre,
        usuario,
      };
      const response = await firebase.database().ref('usuarios').push(payload);
      // reset form
      identificacionEl.value = null;
      nombreEl.value = null;
      usuarioEl.value = null;
      // reload the page
      window.location.reload();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('submitHandler', error);
  }
} 

window.onload = () => {
  getData();
};
```

Solución compleja, el la que puedes guardar cada registro de tu formulario en [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), para después ir mostrando cada registro en una tabla y añadir un botón que mandé esos registros locales a `firebase database`.

Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style = "color: rgb(0, 175, 175);">Manta</h1>
  <h4 style = "color: rgb(4, 152, 211); font-style: italic;">Take it faster</h4>
  <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();return addNode()">
    <label for="">Identificación: </label>
    <input required type="text" id="txtIdentificacion"><br>
    <label for="">Nombre: </label>
    <input required type="text" id="txtNombre"><br>
    <label for="">Usuario: </label> 
    <input required type="text" id="txtUsuario"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="btnGuardar">Guardar localmente</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div>
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Identificación</th>
        <th>Nombre</th> 
        <th>Usuario</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- table-rows will be auto inserted here -->
    </table>
    <br>
    <button id="bulkInsertBtn" onclick="bulkInsert()">
      Guardar datos locales en firebase
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript (archivo main.js)

```
  // get the previous data stored in localstorage and assign it to the "data" variable
  // otherwise initialize data as a empty array
  const previousData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('items'));
  let data = previousData || [];

  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  function createTable() {
    const container = document.getElementById('table');
    if (container) {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const element = data[i];
        // create a tr
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (const key in element) {
          if (element.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const dataField = element[key];
            // create a td
            const td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerText = dataField;
            tr.appendChild(td);
          }
        }
        container.appendChild(tr);
      }
    }
  }

  function addNode() {
    // inputs
    const identificacionEl = document.getElementById('txtIdentificacion');
    const nombreEl = document.getElementById('txtNombre');
    const usuarioEl = document.getElementById('txtUsuario');
    // input values
    const identificacion = identificacionEl.value;
    const nombre = nombreEl.value;
    const usuario = usuarioEl.value;

    if (identificacion && nombre && usuario) {
      const payload = {
        identificacion,
        nombre,
        usuario,
      };
      data.push(payload);
      window.localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
      // reset form
      identificacionEl.value = null;
      nombreEl.value = null;
      usuarioEl.value = null;
      // reload the page
      window.location.reload();
    }
  } 

  async function bulkInsert() {
    try {
      if (data.length) {
        const operations = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          const element = data[i];
          operations.push(insertData(element));
        }
        await Promise.all(operations);
        window.location.reload();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('bulkInsert error', error);
    }
  }

async function insertData({ identificacion, nombre, usuario}) {
  try {
    if (identificacion && nombre && usuario) {
      const payload = { identificacion, nombre, usuario};
      const response = await firebase.database().ref('usuarios').push(payload);
      data = data.filter(x => x.identificacion !== identificacion);
      window.localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
      return response;
    } else {
      console.log('faltan parametros');
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  createTable();
  const btn = document.getElementById('bulkInsertBtn');
  if (!data.length) {
    btn.style = 'display: none';
  }
};
```